# Merging points that are close together in an array

Tags: replacement, data

What I have is a dataset `data = Transpose[{x,y}]` that looks something like this (in practice I have a ton of these, some of them with much more points, but I figured I would stick to the one that gets the point across) [image]

What I would like to do is cluster points that are close together. What I mean by this I would envision in a few ways. The easiest is that if $x_{i+1}-x_i \leq x_{min}$ and $y_{i+1}-y_{i} \leq y_{min}$, I would like to replace $\{x_i,y_i\}$ and $\{x_{i+1},y_{i+1}\}$ by their mean x and y value in some new dataset.

Now, I suppose for this one would use `Differences`, together with some criteria `xmin` and `ymin` that the user sets. I have to admit that I get stuck very quickly, but let me at least paste the data and give some starting point

```
data = {{1.65, 0.}, {2.33287, 0.0126948}, {4.38148, 0.0676046}, {7.79583, 
  0.193945}, {12.5759, 0.297199}, {18.7218, 0.337641}, {21.5625, 
  0.362302}, {26.2333, 0.363058}, {28.7531, 0.37794}, {35.1106, 
  0.375451}, {37.05, 0.377025}, {45.3537, 0.36488}, {46.4531, 
  0.378526}, {56.9625, 0.343219}, {56.9625, 0.352874}, {68.5781, 
  0.344392}, {81.3, 0.314263}, {95.1281, 0.303282}, {110.063, 
  0.280359}, {126.103, 0.255028}, {143.25, 0.254428}, {161.503, 
  0.21491}, {180.863, 0.199256}};

xmin = 3;
ymin = 0.3;
diff = Differences@data;
```

Note that these values for `xmin` and `ymin` are just a guess, one would obviously have to tune them to their own preference. Then.. we start running into conditionals and loops and such. I know that in Mathematica one generally doesn't use loops, but mappings and tables instead. I have to admit that I honestly don't really know where to go with this. Something using `Replace`, `Abs[data[[i,All]]-data[[i+1,All]]]<=xmin&&Abs[data[[All,i]]-data[[All,i]]]<=ymin`, `Mean[..]` and then some more.

So my question is if someone could help me out set this up. I would be happy if for example the first two points get merged, and some of the points around the maximum, but the rest should be more or less left alone. That is to give an indication of what I am after; I can do the tweaking myself of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 ListPlot[Mean /@ Gather[data, Norm[(#1 - #2)/{10,1}] < .3 &] ]
```

[image]

or your actual criteria like this:

```
ListPlot[Mean /@ 
  Gather[data, 
   Abs[(#1 - #2)[[1]]] < 3 && Abs[(#1 - #2)[[2]]] < .3 &] ]
```

Comment: Amazing. Mathematica has such a variety of built in stuff, it's crazy. So essentially what this does is tell Gather what it should consider as two points being equal, and then takes the means of the points that are equal according to those criteria?

Comment: yes its always useful to hunt for a built in capability.  If you run this : `Gather[data, Norm[(#1 - #2)/{10, 1}] < .3 &] // MatrixForm`  it should be clear how that works.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this will be a better optimized and more robust solution:

```
ratio = .3

r = -Subtract @@ MinMax@# & /@ Transpose@dat;
crit = RankedMin[Norm[#/r] & /@ Differences[dat], 
   Floor[ratio Length@dat]];
datn = Mean /@ Split[dat, Norm[(#1 - #2)/r] <= crit &];
ListPlot@datn
```

The only thing you should do is to specify the ratio, which represents how much points you want to merge, here it's `0.3` which means 30% of the points will be merged.

Then everything will be done by Mathematica~ Even simpler, right? You won't need to adjust those xvalues and yvalues on your own~

Comment: I haven't fully gone through the code yet, but what does ratio specify? The amount of points I want to end up with, or how close the points are? As in, I don't necessarily want to end up with less points if all of them are well separated.

Comment: It represents how much points you want to delete. 0.3 means delete 30% of the points. If you want no points deleted, you can simply set it to 0. You may plot `ListPlot[Norm[#/r] & /@ Differences[dat]]` before you select the ratio, check how near you want the points to be. If you still want to specify everything by yourself, you can manually set `r`.

Comment: Also, when there're numerous points, and they're ordered, Using `Split` will be much better in speed, but if your points' order is messed up, then use `Gather`. You may check it yourself.